# OpenCL conditional atomic functions

Tags: opencl

Can atomic functions be placed inside if conditions or for loops in **OpenCL**. If possible can someone provide me with an example kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can.

There's no special lock-step requirement for atomic functions like there is for barriers.

It's common to reduce a group-wide result of a calculation, and then only one work-item from the group updates the global buffer with this sub-result.

```
if (get_local_id(0) == 0)
    atomic_add(result_ptr, group_result);
```